When integrating, what does it mean to integrate with respect to something?
I have seen multiple questions similar to mine but am still not able to understand what it means to integrate with respect to a variable. Lets take the indefinite integral below
$$\int x\sqrt{5+2x^2}\, dx$$
after a u substitution it would look something like
$$\frac{1}{4}\int \sqrt{u}\,du $$
From what i understand, the dx tells us that we are integrating with respect to x, meaning we are taking the area between the x axis and the curve (when it is a definite integral)
and when i u substitute, i transform the axis into my u substitution which is $ 5+2x^2 $, but i dont understand how i can take the area under the curve (which is now $\sqrt{5+2x^2}$)
as you can see in my attached graph (link) the curve is entirely below the "axis", and while i understand that a negative area is possible, since the original function has a positive area from 0 to x>0, I dont understand how you would geometrically explain the "new area" to take on the graph. I know my question is a bit unorthodox.
Ultimately my confusion stems from what dx and du mean, and i've seen a lot of answers but I am utterly dumbfounded as to how to visualize integrating the new function across the new axis. I am trying to understand what the new area would look like graphically, but am very confused, I would appreciate if someone could explain this to me.
The graph i am refering to : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6qwg4isk2v

Pick integration bounds and convince yourself that the $dx$-integral and the $du$-integral agree. What does this tell you about with respect to what we integrate ?

Don't try to understand what $dx$ and $du$ mean on their own, those are hard things. You could think of them intuitively as small changes, if you think of integrals as areas (sums of small rectangles), but I recommend treating the whole thing $\int _, dx$ as a one object (which is how it is actually defined in the beginning). Learning properly about what $dx$ is takes some more advanced knowledge.

I input both into a calculator and got 1.66 for du integral and 1.22 for the dx integral? interval was 0 to 1 for both @KurtG.

So for now i can say that the variable after the d in dx or du tell me on which variable I can perform my operations? like the inverse power rule and inverse chain rule? would that be a sufficient way to look at $ \int dx $ for now? @Esgeriath

You need to put limits on the integrals to make sense of these as areas. If the original integral were taken for x from 0 to 1 say, then $u = 1+2x^2$ will have u limits from 1 to 3. Then the area under the graph of $y = x\sqrt{1+2x^2}$ for x from 0 to 1 is the same as one quarter of the area under the graph of $y=\sqrt{u}$ for u from 1 to 3.

$0$ and $1$ for both. Totally wrong. You must transform the bounds.

Omg i think i just understood it. until now i was thinking of u as just what I substituted it for, but now I think I get it? i was thinking that the axis for the new integral would be the axis of what we substituted u for, so the axis would be the parabola of 5+2(x)^2, which is what was confusing me(how would the parabola be an axis), but I think just how for an integral wrt dx the axis is y=0, now the axis is just "renamed" to u, is that correct? @KurtG.

I do not want to unravel that comment. Practice more examples and you will finally get it.

Your axis is $u$ because the substitution $u = 5+2x^2$ amounts to a change of coordinates. There's nothing wrong with nonlinear axes (e.g. log axis is very common). That is why you have to change the bounds of your integral, that is if in the $x$-coordinate system your $x$ bounds were from 0 to 1, in the transformed $u$-coordinate system the bounds are from 5 to 7.

Oops, $u = 5+2x^2$ not $u = 1+2x^2$ as I said. Same idea though.

@RandyMarsh So it seems I was correct before. My doubt is what this would look like on the graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6qwg4isk2v

@KurtG. As Randy Marsh pointed out my axis is $5+2x^2$ , all I am confused about is how someone would graph this? what would it look like. I would appreciate it a lot if you do not wish to unravel my comment, what exactly do you mean by practice more examples, do you mean practice more u substitution? it would help if you could point me in a direction.

Do I have to unravel the comments of two users now? By practicing more examples I mean convince yourself of the invariance of a definite integral when you do the substitutions properly (variable plus integration limits). If you need a graph to understand this find a simple enough example.

You can't graph everything on the same graph because these objects live in different coordinate systems. Take an easier example, say $\int 2x dx$ with substitution $u=2 x$. The $u$ axis is not the graph of $f(x)=2x$, it is still the $x$-axis but scaled by a factor of 2.

Yeah i finally understood that was my mistake, thanks for the help @RandyMarsh


"my confusion stems from what dx and du mean"

The most transparent way of understanding $dx$ and $du$ in integration is as infinitesimal increments, and the integral - in terms of an infinite sum of infinitesimals.  When you introduce a change of variables, for example $u=10x$, the infinitesimal increments transform accordingly, in this case $du=10dx$.  Of course, the bounds of integration change accordingly: if $x$ varies from $a$ to $b$, the new variable $u$ will vary from $10a$ to $10b$.  Of course, similar rules apply for nonlinear changes of variable.

This is an answer that i found to be very clearly worded and easy to understand, thank you for taking the time to answer my question, I shall mark this with the green tick. Thanks @Mikhail.

Glad to be of help.  In general, infinitesimals make calculus easier to understand, even though not everybody around MSE agrees :-)  For more on infinitesimals, see this and this.

Thanks for the extra resources! appreciate it a lot :)
